# :hover persistent when moving DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

When moving a DOM element from under the mouse the CSS :hover state stays persistent until the mouse pointer is moved.

http://jsfiddle.net/mMzPd/ ( div element will be red after click until user moves the mouse. )

I'm looking for any recommended solutions to turn the hover off or reset hover state when the DOM element moves. Alternatively when the user clicks the element.

I've understood that you can't directly control CSS states through javascript so my best current solution is to toggle a HTML class with Jquerys mouseenter() and mouseleave(). I don't really find this fix elegant, nor does it scale well to a browser with javascript disabled.

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('div').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({'margin-top':'100px'});
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/mMzPd/4/ )

Any solutions closer to pure Css out there? Would ideally like to keep style rules out of my Javascript.

This issue is showing in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Firefox toggles the :hover "correctly".

Comment: What browser do you use? The box reverts to green as is moves away in Firefox 18 + Ubuntu

Comment: Chrome and Internet Explorer has this behavior. Not sure about Opera, Safari etc. Firefox resets :hover state.

Comment: Wow. Even IE10 has this behaviour. So much for browser improvement.

Answer (score 2):

What about using another pseudo-class selector after :hover?

```
div:active{
  background-color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mMzPd/6/

Comment: Smart and elegant fix. Unfortunately the :focus behavior is pretty inconsistent between browser. This solution works in IE10 but not in Chrome. If possible, I would like to keep the other Css states "free" for other uses. Thank you for the answer though!