# IE9 hover bug - Hover state stays after moving a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

This is obviously a much cut down down version of the actual application, however the bug is still the same...

We have a table with rows that can be moved up/down with controls in the row, and to signify this the move controls have a hover state. In the following jsbin http://jsbin.com/asasak/1 in IE9 you'll see that the hover state stays after the row has been moved.

Any ideas? I've even tried changing the row's class when it is moved and then removing the class but the hover state still stays!

Comment: I checked it in each different version of IE and the hover state seems to work fine for me, unless there is something that I am missing

Comment: hover state stays upon click in IE 9

Comment: so when you click one of the boxes to move the row up and down the hover state stays blue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [:hover persistent when moving DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317760/hover-persistent-when-moving-dom-element) and I tried the `:active` solution but that was leaving that state attached to the element after the move which was not good.

One way to work around this problem is to replace the element instead of moving it. It's a hack, has a small performance impact that you might not want to add and it's not as elegant as I'd have liked, but this is working for me in IE8.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('click', 'a', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var row = $this.closest('tr');
      var index = row.index();
      var lastIndex = row.siblings().length;

      if ($this.hasClass('up') && index === 0 || $this.hasClass('down') && index === lastIndex) {
        return;
      }

      if ($this.hasClass('up')) {
        row.clone().insertBefore(row.prev());
      } else {
        row.clone().insertAfter(row.next());
      }

      row.remove();
    });
});
```

Note: Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate the *click* event which avoids having to `.clone()` elements with their events each time.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i think we might just disable the hover state in lte ie9 instead as this probably won't be suitable for our app

Comment: Good idea. The impact wasn't really that noticeable but I agree that disabling for `IE9` is the simplest solution!